# Can we make SFDC report with Profile object.

Tags: profile

I want to create SFDC report on Profile object. I could not find standard report on profile object and neither Custom report can be created on this . Is there any way to report this. ?

Comment: What functionality or requirement you need to create reports on profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly say, you can't create a report on profiles, so there's a couple of options to get at this information in a report-like fashion:

(1) Use the dataloader to export the profile information and import into Excel for your reporting.  Not a great solution and you can't retrieve related objects, so getting at information about users with those profiles would require additional exports and merging.

(2) Create a Visualforce page to generate the report.  As long as you aren't looking for a report that is particularly complex or has a lot of calculations associated with it, it isn't a prohibitive amount of effort.